# RMO inequality problem

Tags: inequality, contest-math

If $a,b,c,d,e>1$, then prove that:
$$\frac{a^2}{b-1} + \frac{b^2}{c-1} + \frac{d^2}{e-1} + \frac{c^2}{a-1} + \frac{e^2}{d-1} \ge 20. $$

I don't know how to begin. What should be the approach?

Comment: Hint: let $a=a'+1,b=b'+1,\ldots$.

Comment: Wouldn't that make it more complicated

Comment: No. It's a standard technique. Often we deal with inequalities whose variables are positive reals, but this problem is a little different. In order to apply the standard inequalities (like C-S, AM-GM), it's natural to substitute like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that we can rewrite your expression as

$$ \left( \frac{a^2}{b-1} + \frac{b^2}{c-1} + \frac{c^2}{a-1} \right) + \left( \frac{d^2}{e-1} + \frac{e^2}{d-1} \right) \geq 20. $$

Let us consider first the baby problem of finding the minimum value of $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x-1}$ assuming $x > 1$. The minimum is readily seen to be attained at $x = 2$ with value $4$.

Next, consider the problem of finding the minimum value of

$$ \frac{d^2}{e-1} + \frac{e^2}{d-1} =  f(d) \frac{d-1}{e-1} + f(e) \frac{e-1}{d-1} $$

assuming $d,e > 1$. The arithmetic-geometric inequality shows that

$$ f(d) \frac{d-1}{e-1} + f(e) \frac{e-1}{d-1} \geq 2 \sqrt{f(d)f(e)} \geq 2f(2) = 8 $$

where the minimum value of $8$ is indeed attained when $d = e = 2$.

Finally, consider the problem of finding the minimum value of

$$ \frac{a^2}{b-1} + \frac{b^2}{c-1} + \frac{c^2}{a-1} = f(a)\frac{a-1}{b-1} + f(b)\frac{b-1}{c-1} + f(c)\frac{c-1}{a-1} $$

assuming $a,b,c > 1$. Again, the arithmetic-geometric inequality shows that

$$ f(a)\frac{a-1}{b-1} + f(b)\frac{b-1}{c-1} + f(c)\frac{c-1}{a-1} \geq 3 (f(a)f(b)f(c))^{\frac{1}{3}} \geq 3f(2) = 12 $$

where the minimum indeed attained at $a = b = c = 2$.

Combining everything above, we obtain the required result.

Comment: Question: how did you figure out that this approach would lead to the result needed? Whenever I try, I'm clouded by various possibilities in which it could be started. And the thing   I feel is that my try would be one of many and so it might just lead to making it all more complicated. How do you get confident of your approach ?

Comment: I mean, you took a calculus approach. Somebody else took an algebraic approach. How am I to know which path to take? How am I to surmise which one goes the right way?

Comment: @user115962 You can never be sure, but the thing that jumped to my mind was the fact that your problem seems to split into two "smaller" independent problems which have less variables and so seem easier. I was taught to always try and solve the most trivial instance of a problem first and so I decided to check the one variable case and see if it can be used to solve the general case. I think the most important part in solving this problem is identifying the role of the expression $\frac{x^2}{x-1}$ and the inequality $\frac{x^2}{x-1} \geq 4$.

Comment: @user115962 On what level are you? A college student using inequalities to solve problems or a high school student trying to solve olympiad inequalities? If it's the latter, then I would say that algebraic approaches are definitely the path you should take.

Comment: BTW, there is no calculus involved in my solution. You can deduce the inequality $\frac{x^2}{x-1} \geq 4$ using calculus but also algebraically. No matter how you do it, the solution from that point on involves only the AG-inequality.

Comment: The splitting into independent problems is the decomposition of the permutation (used in the rearrangement inequality) into disjoint cycles.

Comment: @levap  Nicely Done! The solution illustrates wonderfully how one can consider a simpler problem to solve a more "complicated" and "intimidating" problem. :)

Answer (score 15):

Note that $x^2-4(x-1) = (x-2)^2\ge 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and hence $x^2\ge 4(x-1)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. As such, we have
$$ \frac{a^2}{b-1} + \frac{b^2}{c-1} + \frac{d^2}{e-1} + \frac{c^2}{a-1} + \frac{e^2}{d-1} \ge 4\left(\frac{a-1}{b-1} + \frac{b-1}{c-1} + \frac{c-1}{a-1} + \frac{d-1}{e-1} + \frac{e-1}{d-1}\right). $$
So it suffices to show
$$\frac{a-1}{b-1} + \frac{b-1}{c-1} + \frac{c-1}{a-1} + \frac{d-1}{e-1} + \frac{e-1}{d-1}\ge 5.$$
Can you see how to finish?

Comment: This is better than the accept answer.

Comment: @TahaAkbari I would rather say that both the answers are looking at the same thing with a different perspective. While this answer makes it look short and quick, the accepted answer gives an insight on how one can not only solve this problem, but also get at other problems.

Answer (score 8):

Using Cauchy-Scwarz to 
\begin{align*}
\frac{a_1}{\sqrt{x_1}}, \frac{a_2}{\sqrt{x_2}}, \ldots, \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{x_n}} \\
\sqrt{x_1}, \sqrt{x_2}, \ldots, \sqrt{x_n}
\end{align*}
we get
\begin{align*}
\frac{a_1^2}{x_1}+\frac{a_2^2}{x_2}+\cdots + \frac{a_n^2}{x_n} \geq \frac{(a_1+a_2+\cdots + a_n)^2}{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}
\end{align*}
Hence we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{a^2}{b-1}+\frac{b^2}{c-1}+\frac{d^2}{e-1}+\frac{c^2}{a-1}+\frac{e^2}{d-1} \geq \frac{(a+b+c+d+e)^2}{a+b+c+d+e-5}
\end{align*}
Putting $x=a+b+c+d+e$, we need to prove
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^2}{x-5} \geq 20
\end{align*}Since $x > 5$, this can be written as  $x^2 -20x + 100 \geq 0$. This follows readily since 
\begin{align*} x^2-20x+100 = (x-10)^2\end{align*}

The proof also shows that the numerators can be any permutation of $a^2,b^2,c^2,d^2,e^2$

Comment: This is also called Titu's lemma for the record :)

Answer (score 6):

The functions $x^2$ and $(x-1)$ are both increasing in $x$.  Therefore, by the rearrangement inequality, the sum is $ \geq \sum \frac{a^2}{a-1}$ which is easier to control, in fact each term of this sum is $\geq 4$.

Answer (score 6):

By Cauchy Schwarz, $($given expression$)(a+b+c+d+e-5)\geq(a+b+c+d+e)^2$

Now this shows $($given expression$)\geq \dfrac{(a+b+c+d+e)^2}{a+b+c+d+e-5}$

Now $(a+b+c+d+e)^2=(a+b+c+d+e-5)^2+2\times(a+b+c+d+e-5)\times 5+25$ hence on division by $a+b+c+d+e-5$ we get $a+b+c+d+e-5+10+\dfrac{25}{a+b+c+d+e-5}=(a+b+c+d+e-5)+\dfrac{25}{a+b+c+d+e-5}+10$

Letting $x=a+b+c+d+e-5$ we note $x\geq0$ and the above is $x+\dfrac{25}{x}+10\geq 10+10=20$ by AM-GM.